# Can I merge my LaunchPad login to this account?

Tags: support, status-completed, login, launchpad

I've seen this question multiple times, but they're all dated, so I don't feel appropriate to resurrect any of those ancient threads. Can a mod help me merge my StackExchange account (which is linked to Google and GitHub) with my Launchpad account (`[REDACTED]`) ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add Launchpad login to your account, you can click [this multi user link](https://askubuntu.com/users/mylogins/current) (works for who ever clicks it) to go to your profile and then click on "add more logins"

> [image: Screenshot of logins page]

For more information you can see [this page](https://askubuntu.com/help/edit-credentials) in the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help)